# Built In Form: ShowDataForm Properties

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**

I would like to read in the inputs of Excel's built in ShowDataForm function. However there is no documentation or information on how to do so.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.showdataform

**Possible Solutions:**

1.) Use OCR or On Screen Text reading as a work around, but that is very difficult to implement, well at least for me.

2.) Create the ShowDataForm from scratch to allow for data reading. Goal is to not re-invent the wheel.

I have searched all over and the only information I could find regarding properties is from 2012.
Stating "The built-in data form is fixed, you can't change it in any way."
My goal is not to change/modify, but simply extract the data. Presently there is no way to my knowledge to do so.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/showdataform-properties/0cb96a3e-41c2-4ce8-8e75-74b9193aefa3

**Code:**

ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
' Does not contain any Properties/Methods to read from

**Helpful Information**

https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/08/02/mysteries-of-the-excel-data-form/